# How to monitor CPU Load m memory and traffic of a remote server using snmp and mrtg

Tags: snmp, mrtg

I am using ubuntu 15.x where I have configured MRTG. I have configured it to monitor  traffic of a remote system that I have done successfully. Now I have to monitor CPU and memory statistics of that remote server. 
Should I configure remote snmp or My ubuntu system MRTG config for this purpose.?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your remote server is Linux too. 
Both tasks have to be done:

1) configure and run snmpd daemon on remote machine. Basically this means creating/editing /etc/snmpd.conf file manually or with snmpconf utility and starting snmpd service. To test your setup it's handy to have net-snmp utils installed on a local machine (snmpget, snmpwalk, etc).

- Check that remote host is responding to snmp requests issue with command:

  `$ snmpget -v2c -c public remoteHostNameOrIP sysUpTime.0
  DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (2039801384) 236 days, 2:06:53.84`
- get processors load values (example):

  `$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public remoteHostNameOrIP  .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.768 = INTEGER: 73
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.769 = INTEGER: 18
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.770 = INTEGER: 11
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.771 = INTEGER: 14
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.772 = INTEGER: 24
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.773 = INTEGER: 22
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.774 = INTEGER: 32
  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.775 = INTEGER: 23`

2) add cpu/memory snmp OID targets of your choice to your local MRTG config.
OIDs you are interested in are defined in UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt and HOST-RESOURCES-MIB..txt files (likely located in /usr/share/snmp/mibs).